# How to transform rectangle A with contents into rectangle B, using an affine transform matrix

Tags: javascript, svg, affinetransform

**I'm not good at English, so I apologize for using a translator to ask questions.**

I am trying to resize a rectangle using drag.

But what I am curious about now is when the rectangle A is changed to the rectangle B,

I wonder how the other rectangles inside the rectangle will change.

I know all the vertices of rectangles A and B and the rectangles inside rectangle A.

I wonder how the rectangles inside A should move to B.

[image]

before move (RECT A) | after move (RECT B)

(x1,y1)   =>    (x1',y1')

(x2,y2)   =>    (x2,y2) (same positon)

(x3,y3)   => (x3',y3')

(x4,y4)   => (x4',y4')

When changing as in the image above, I want to use the affine matrix to properly change the elements inside the rectangle A to the inside of B.

How do we calculate the coordinates of each of the inner rectangles of A?

I want to implement this calculation process in JavaScript, but I am curious how to do it.

Comment: Should the red & blue rectangles change size?

Comment: yes scale rectB/ rectA

Comment: They don't move. Treat (x1--x1') as your x-axis, and (y4--y4') as your y-axis (or, treat x2,y2 as origin: it's the same thing), then scale the entire coordinate system across those axes and you're done.